# C# On or Before DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to write if If statement that executes if the CreatedDate is on or before the next 1 hour. Is there a way to do this?

Something like:

```
if (CreatedOn.ToUniversalTime() <= DateTime.Now.AddHours(1).ToUniversalTime())
{
}
```

Would that be right or is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: Wait -- you have *created* dates up to one hour in the *future*? :D Your code looks fine, BTW.

Comment: looks good - of course if you are uncertain you could have just played a bit or just written some **learning tests** - it's not a big deal to check if this is right ;)

Comment: Could it be that you meant to ask this instead: Check if it has been an hour or less since the creation date?

Comment: To avoid going to local and back to universal, use `DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1)`. I always try to avoid this so that I can think less about what happens at daylite savings time changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your approach is mostly fine. After all, look at your description:

> "if the CreatedDate is on or before the next 1 hour"

That doesn't talk about subtracting one time from another - it talks about comparing `CreatedDate` with "the next hour" i.e. one hour from now.

So:

```
DateTime hourFromNowUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1);
if (CreatedOn.UniversalTime() <= hourFromNowUtc)
```

that looks pretty clean to me - except you need to be aware of what `CreatedOn` really is. Is it local? Unspecified? Already universal? Unfortunately [`DateTime` is problematic in this respect](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html)... if you were using [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) there'd be no cause for doubt ;)

Comment: Thanks Jon. That's what I was looking for. And thinks for not giving me a hard time for how I asked the question. :)

Comment: Ha!  +1 for (mostly) shameless promotion of the project you work on.  Also because it really would make this easier to deal with.  Darn `DateTime`...

Comment: @Zannjaminderson: I'm certainly *hoping* that I haven't wasted my evening implementing the Islamic calendar :)

Comment: @JonSkeet, If I delete my post will you promise to take my name out of your answer :-)? +1 - this I'd clearly a better approach.

Comment: @JonSkeet I feel a Skeet joke coming on here - "Jon Skeet implemented the Islamic calendar in 15 minutes one evening whilst watching the news."

Answer (score -1):

There are several alternatives how you can do it. For example `DateTime.Now - CreatedOn` returns a `TimeSpan` value which says how much time is between these two. You can compare it to 1 hour or less.